# Save a HTML5 canvas to a folder on a server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, canvas

I wrote a small JavaScript-based paint program using a HTML5 canvas. What I'm trying to implement now is the ability to save the drawing to a folder on a server. The filename should be something like this: "artist"+"title"+"date" (I'm using prompts to get the artist name and the title). 
How can I do this? I know I have to do something like this:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

and then use Ajax to call a PHP script. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveImg.php",
    data: { 
        imgBase64: dataURL
    }
}).done(function(o) {
console.log('saved'); 
});
```

But how do I get the artist name and the title to the PHP script? As far as I know the file name is defined inside the PHP script, right?

Greetings

Comment: Add more properties to the data object and assign values accordingly

Comment: `data: { 
        imgBase64: dataURL,
        artist:'artist name'
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished in the following way ...

**ᴊᴀᴠᴀꜱᴄʀɪᴘᴛ**

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
$.post('saveImg.php', {
    imgBase64: dataURL,
    artist: 'ramy',
    title: 'paint',
    date: new Date().toDateString()
}, function(o) {
    console.log('saved');
});
```

**ᴘʜᴘ**

```
<?php
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = 'images/'.$artist.'_'.$title.'_'.$date.'.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
```